# How does NumPy in-place sort work on views?

Tags: python, numpy

Could you please help me understand the output of these two sorting attempts:

Attempt 1

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a[::-1].sort()
print(a)
# prints [3 2 1]
```

I somehow understand that `a[::-1]` is a view and hence sorting in place leads to descending order instead of the usual ascending order.

Attempt 2

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a = a[::-1]
a.sort()
print(a)
# prints [1 2 3]
```

What has changed here? We are still operating on a view so why is the output different?

Comment: I think it's because you assign back to `a`.

Comment: `print` after each line.  Add the output to your question, would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's avoid the complications of "assigning back", and use a new variable name:

```
In [75]: x=np.array([1,2,3]); x1 = x[::-1]    
In [76]: x1, x1.base
Out[76]: (array([3, 2, 1]), array([1, 2, 3]))

In [77]: x1.sort()

In [78]: x1, x1.base
Out[78]: (array([1, 2, 3]), array([3, 2, 1]))
```

So `x1` as been sorted in-place, and in the process that changes the base (which is still `x`).

In the one liner, `x` changes in the same way:

```
In [79]: x=np.array([1,2,3]); x[::-1].sort()
In [80]: x
Out[80]: array([3, 2, 1])
```

So the same thing happens in both cases.  It's just obscured by the `a=a[::-1]` step.

Comment: looks like sorting in place operates on the base. Everything using the same base will be affected, right?

x = np.array([1,4,3, 10, 2]); y = x[::2]; print(y, y.base)   -->  [1 3 2] [ 1  4  3 10  2]     and   

x.sort(); print(y, y.base)  --> [ 1  3 10] [ 1  2  3  4 10]

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Have a look here:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a = a[::-1]
>>> a
array([3, 2, 1])
>>> a.base
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.base
array([3, 2, 1])
```

In your attempt 2, the base array is in fact sorted in reverse order, but since you reassigned back to `a`, and that's the one you're printing, you'll see a sorted version of the view, not the base.